# Proving that a polynomial is irreducible over a splitting field

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

As titled.Let E be the splitting field of $x^3-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.I know that $E = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\omega)$ where $\omega$ is the primitive root of $x^3-1$. Now,let $g(x) = x^2-7$,I want to show that g(x) is irreducible over $E$.Intuitively, I know that the roots of g(x) (namely,$\sqrt{7}$ and $-\sqrt{7}$) cannot be expressed as a combination of $\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\omega$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\omega)$.Can we prove it using Galois theory?If there's a root $\beta \in E$, then there's a subfield $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$,with degree 2.But that doesn't seem to contradict the condition that $|\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\omega)/\mathbb{Q}| = 6$. So what's wrong with this argument?
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The field $\mathbb Q(\omega)$ has degree $2$ over $\mathbb Q$.  It's the unique quadratic number field in your splitting field, so you must prove that it is not $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 7)$ (in fact, $\mathbb Q(\omega)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3)$).

Comment: shouldn't it be $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$? Also, how to prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ is the unique quadatic number field?

Comment: Yes, typo. Sorry about that.

Comment: How many subgroups of order $3$ does $S_3$ have?

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Comment: You can show that if $\sqrt {7}\in E$ then $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt {7},\omega)\subseteq E$. The first field is of degree $4$ over $\mathbb {Q} $ and latter of degree $6$. This contradicts the tower theorem. This does not require Galois theory.